# Is there any way to insert a form from Page B into my Page A (same domain) using only html and css?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Basically I need to get my contact form from Page B and insert it into my Page A, but its showing the entire page B (including the header of the website) in page A. I just need the form part only. Is there a way ?

```
<h1>
<iframe allowfullscreen="false" height="700px" src="https://" style="border: none;" width="1000px"></iframe>
</h1>
```

Example of [Page B](https://www.dominos.com.my/pages/services/?p=customerFeedback).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `<iframe>` contains content from a different domain, there's pretty much nothing you can do. The parent page controls the size of the frame and whether it's visible, and can put its own content over the frame by positioning etc, but it can't directly affect the way the actual frame content is rendered.

In short, you can change the styling of an iframe like width, height but you don't have any control on the inside elements.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's no way to finish your job directly, but you can try some workaround ways
you can just make a new page consists of B's forms, then use iframe to include this page, or you can use frameworks to make several components then reuse these materials to finish your requirement. I don't know exactly what's your requirement and what's the painful-point you want to handle, give it a try, and other guys advice.